# Keycloak - How to refresh token witj Java client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm looking for refresh token by using the Java Admin Client https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/integration/admin-client

Cannot find anything about it

Regards

EDIT :

finally I go that :

```
public AccessTokenResponse executeRefresh(String refreshToken) {
    String url = "https://url/auth" + "/realms/" + keycloakRealm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    Configuration kcConfig = new Configuration(authServerUrl, keycloakRealm, keycloakInternalClientId, null, null);
    Http http = new Http(kcConfig, (params, headers) -> {
    });
    return http.<AccessTokenResponse>post(url)
            .authentication()
            .client()
            .form()
            .param("grant_type", "refresh_token")
            .param("refresh_token", refreshToken)
            .param("client_id", keycloakInternalClientId)
            .param("client_secret", keycloakInternalClientSecret)
            .response()
            .json(AccessTokenResponse.class)
            .execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.tokenManager().refreshToken()` can refresh token. For example:

```java
// Create a Keycloak client
Keycloak kc = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
        .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
        .realm("master")
        .username("admin")
        .password("password")
        .clientId("admin-cli")
        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
        .build();

TokenManager tokenManager = kc.tokenManager();
// get access token
AccessTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = tokenManager.getAccessToken();
System.out.println(accessTokenResponse.getRefreshToken());
// Refresh token
accessTokenResponse = tokenManager.refreshToken();
System.out.println(accessTokenResponse.getRefreshToken());
```

Comment: Hello. The problem the UI  don't keep the password, it send refresh token when token expire. So I only have the username and refresh token. I don't find anything in keycloak java client for that.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly Java Admin Client does not have this kind of functionality (hopefully will have in the future)

For now, look at this answer:
[Refresh access_token via refresh_token in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386337/refresh-access-token-via-refresh-token-in-keycloak)

Answer (score 0):

Have achieved it through RestTemplate inside my spring-boot application.

Below is the code I have used to get refresh token :-

```
public ResponseEntity<RefreshTokenResponse> refreshToken(String refreshToken) {
    String url = authUrl+ "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    map.add("refresh_token", refreshToken);
    map.add("client_id", clientId);
    map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity response =
            restTemplate.exchange(url,
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    entity,
                    Object.class);
    return response;}
```

RefreshTokenResponse :-

```
    @Data
public class RefreshTokenResponse {
    private AccessTokenResponse token;
}
```

> Keycloak v19.0.0
>
> authUrl :- where keycloak server is running. my case
> http://localhost:8080/
>
> ream :- your realm name

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I managed to make Keycloak client do this job for me after spending some time with the issue. In my case I had to connect to a Keycloak server with password grant type, and use access token to fetch data from a third party protected endpoint in a Spring Boot server side application.

At the end I came up with a service, which provides an access token after initial authentication, and automatic refresh/re-authentication on demand.

I added a `@Configuration` bean, which contained the connection parameters to the third party Keycloak instance:

```java
    package no.currentclient.application.api.config;  // real package name masked

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

    @Configuration
    public class OauthClientConfig {

        public record OauthConfig(String realm, String authServerUrl, String clientId, String username, String password) {
        }

        @Bean
        OauthConfig oauthConfig(
                @Value("${client.oauth.realm}") String realm,
                @Value("${client.oauth.auth-server-url}") String authServerUrl,
                @Value("${client.oauth.resource}") String clientId,
                @Value("${client.oauth.username}") String username,
                @Value("${client.oauth.password}") String password
        ) {
            return new OauthConfig(realm,
                    authServerUrl,
                    clientId,
                    username,
                    password);
        }
    }
```

After I created a Spring `Service` which is capable of authenticating, getting and refreshing an access token:

```java
package no.currentclient.application.auth.oauthclient;  // real package name masked

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import no.currentclient.application.api.config.OauthClientConfig;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import org.keycloak.authorization.client.representation.ServerConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.Http;
import org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;

@Service
public class OauthTokenService {

    private final TokenCallable tokenCallable;

    public OauthTokenService(
            OauthClientConfig.OauthConfig oauthConfig,
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient
    ) throws IOException {
        var serverConfiguration = getServerConfiguration(oauthConfig.authServerUrl()+"/auth/realms/"+oauthConfig.realm()+"/.well-known/openid-configuration", okHttpClient);
        var config = new org.keycloak.authorization.client.Configuration(
                // These might all be set to null -> only tokenMinimumTimeToLive is used in TokenCallable...
                null,null,null, null,null);
        var http = new Http(config, (requestParams, requestHeaders) -> requestParams.put("client_id", Collections.singletonList("deichman")));

        tokenCallable = new TokenCallable(oauthConfig.username(), oauthConfig.password(), http, config, serverConfiguration);
    }

    /*
    * Call this method to get hold of an on-demand refreshed auth token. TokenCallable handles the burden of token
    * refresh and re-authentication in case of session timeout.
    */
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return tokenCallable.call();
    }

    private ServerConfiguration getServerConfiguration(String configUrl, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) throws IOException {
        var configRequest = new Request.Builder().url(configUrl).get().build();
        try (var response = okHttpClient.newCall(configRequest).execute()) {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(response.body().string(), ServerConfiguration.class);
        }
    }
}
```

`TokenCallable` hides all the complexity of refresh/re-authentication on demand.

Hope it helps a few struggling with this problem.