# How can I implement JWT refresh token in Quarkus Framework?

Tags: jwt, quarkus

I have tried the sample app of [Quarkus and JWT Security Sample App](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt)
How can I implement JWT refresh token in Quarkus Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You have to options here, which are basically the same, you have to invoke keycloak through the rest api in order to get your refresh token. You can do that by using a rest-client, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386337/refresh-access-token-via-refresh-token-in-keycloak) or an [adapter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-keycloak-admin-client), this are your options with the jwt integration.

If you instead use a different dependency like the [oidc client](https://quarkus.io/guides/security) you will be able to create new tokens and have more options, check this [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security).

Thanks