# How to get refresh token after authenticate via pkce flutter app with keycloak using openid_client?

Tags: flutter, keycloak, openid-connect, refresh-token, pkce

I have the following KeyCloak Client config, to use pkce authentication flow:

```
Realm: REALM

Client ID:              pkce-client
Client Protocol:        openid-connect
Access Type:            public
Standard Flow Enabled:  ON
Valid Redirect URIs:    http://localhost:4200/ 

Advanced Settings:
Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method: S256
```

When authenticating with flutter App with iOS Simulator via openid_client
https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client like this

```
  authenticate() async {

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://$localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM');
    var clientId = 'pkce-client';
    var scopes = List<String>.of(['profile', 'openid']);
    var port = 4200;

    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId);

    urlLauncher(String url) async {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }

    var authenticator = new Authenticator(
        client,
        scopes: scopes,
        port: port,
        urlLancher: urlLauncher,
    );

    var auth = await authenticator.authorize();
    var token= await auth.getTokenResponse();
    return token;
  }
```

I get the following response:
[image]

How do I get a new access token with the refresh token?

I tried:

```
POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client_id: pkce-client
grant_type: refresh_token
refresh_token: "received refresh token"
```

but I get:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Invalid client credentials"}
```

How do I need to prepare the request to refresh the access token?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One cause of the problem could be that you need to include the **client_secret** as well in the request. This might be needed if the client is a "confidential" client.

Se the discussion here for further details. [Refresh access_token via refresh_token in Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386337/refresh-access-token-via-refresh-token-in-keycloak)

Comment: I am using pkce, so my client does not have client_secret. Do I need to retrieve the refresh token on another client that has a client_secret? I want to avoid having client_secret in the app.

Comment: PKCE does not have anything to do with the client_secret?

Comment: Access Type is public, so no client_secret is provided.