# Why is refresh_token not refreshed after refresh

Tags: keycloak

I use Keycloaks [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386337/refresh-access-token-via-refresh-token-in-keycloak) endpoint with `grant_type : password` to get a new token.

I use the same endpoint with `grant_type : refresh_token` to refresh my token.

My `access_token` expires after 1 minute, my `refresh_token` after 2 minutes.

I have the following workflow:

1. get a new token -> (`"expires_in": 60, "refresh_expires_in": 120`)
2. after 20 seconds, I refresh the token using the given `refresh_token` from 1
   -> (`"expires_in": 60, "refresh_expires_in": 100`)

I get a new `access_token` which is valid for 60 seconds. However, I also expected a new refresh token with updated `refresh_expires_in`. Instead, I get the same `refresh_token` with a reduced `refresh_expires_in`. So basically I need to login again after 2 minutes.

My client settings are

```json
{
  "clientId": "myclient",
  "name": "",
  "description": "",
  "rootUrl": "",
  "adminUrl": "",
  "baseUrl": "",
  "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "secret": "-------",
  "redirectUris": [
    "*"
  ],
  "webOrigins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "bearerOnly": false,
  "consentRequired": false,
  "standardFlowEnabled": true,
  "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
  "serviceAccountsEnabled": false,
  "publicClient": false,
  "frontchannelLogout": true,
  "protocol": "openid-connect",
  "attributes": {
    "access.token.lifespan": "60",
    "client.secret.creation.time": "1676534835",
    "oauth2.device.authorization.grant.enabled": "false",
    "use.jwks.url": "false",
    "backchannel.logout.revoke.offline.tokens": "false",
    "use.refresh.tokens": "true",
    "tls-client-certificate-bound-access-tokens": "false",
    "oidc.ciba.grant.enabled": "false",
    "backchannel.logout.session.required": "true",
    "client_credentials.use_refresh_token": "false",
    "client.offline.session.idle.timeout": "120",
    "acr.loa.map": "{}",
    "require.pushed.authorization.requests": "false",
    "display.on.consent.screen": "false",
    "client.offline.session.max.lifespan": "120",
    "client.session.max.lifespan": "120",
    "token.response.type.bearer.lower-case": "false",
    "client.session.idle.timeout": "120"
  },
  "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
  "fullScopeAllowed": true,
  "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
  "defaultClientScopes": [
    "web-origins",
    "acr",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "email"
  ],
  "optionalClientScopes": [
    "address",
    "phone",
    "offline_access",
    "microprofile-jwt"
  ],
  "access": {
    "view": true,
    "configure": true,
    "manage": true
  }
}
```

Why are my refresh tokens not updated?